# получение значения по ключу в двоичной min-куче в среднем за конст. время

Tags: алгоритм, структуры, дерево

Добрый день, есть вопрос касательно двоичной min-кучи, как я понял доступ к элементу в этой куче можно получить простым рекурсивным обходом, ну а как получить определенный элемент за константное время ?

Comment: Да вроде - если это не вершина пирамиды - никак.

Comment: Произвольный элемент в куче — ни как. Можно или **минимальный/максимальный в куче**, или **произвольный в хеше**.

Comment: Просто в задании сказано, что нужно использовать двоичную min-кучу и модифицировать её таким образом, чтобы её внутреннее строение было таким же, но при этом доступ к элементу осуществлялся в среднем на конст. время...и мне кажется что это без доп структуры внутри чет как-то вообще нереально.

Comment: @vadosinferno что Вы понимаете под "доступ к элементу"? В куче нет порядка, для доступа должен быть некий ключ. А его тут нет.